# Persistent Bottom Sheet in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, bottom-sheet, material-components

> layout_behavior -
>   **android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior** is not working
>
> this view is not constrained vertically at runtime it will jump

I am getting this error in Androidx only. So how i can resolve this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        ...... child layouts..


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error resolve by replacing**

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

**to**

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

**and**

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

**to**

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

**in activity_main.xml**

Correct code is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        ...... child layouts..


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using androidx libraries, you have to use the [**Material Components Library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
Use the class  [**`com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md) instead of `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior`:

```
<LinearLayout     
  app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
..>
```

or:

```
   <LinearLayout     
      app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    ..>
```

Also change the `ConstraintLayout` to  `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Is there any way to make or set background transparent for persistence bottom sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes to your linear layout and other components :

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

So your linear layout should look like this :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

and also add this three attributes to all the direct child layout of the constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try constraining the LinearLayout vertically?

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```